# Another way of saying "faced with a dilemma"

Tags: phrases

What's another way of saying "I was faced with the dilemma when making a decision"?

Comment: Can you give us a little more context?

Comment: *When you come to a fork in the road, take it* - thank you Yogi.

Comment: I was on the horns of a dilemma.

Comment: What about "I was undecided"?

Comment: Gored by the horns of a dilemma.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply substitute synonyms into your sentence.

*faced* can become...

- confronted

*dilemma* can become...

- problem

> I was **confronted** with the **problem.**

Answer (score 2):

It was a ***[conundrum](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conundrum)***.

It was a ***[quandary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quandary)***.

I was ***[conflicted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conflicted)***.

I was in a ***[predicament](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predicament)***.

I was ***[on the horns of a dilemma](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+horns+of+a+dilemma)***. (as suggested by deadrat)

I was ***[caught between Scylla and Charybdis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Scylla_and_Charybdis)***. (in the context of choosing between two evils)

There are many more potential options, but it's difficult to know what the correct word or phrase is without more detail on what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I was **of two minds**.

Be of two minds:

Be undecided, vacillate between two alternatives, as in *She's of two minds about her new job—it's much closer to home but also less challenging*. Put as "in two minds," this idiom was first recorded in 1853, but variants such as "diverse minds" and "twenty minds" date back to the early 1500s ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/of+two+minds,+be))